# Flask REST client application returns Invalid Credential after successful authentication

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I have a Flask application that authenticates with an endpoint successfully, and receives a valid token in a login() function/route.  If I call another function from login() to return some other data using this valid token, I get a 401 error  invalid credential. If I paste the same code below in my login function, the code runs just fine.

I have verified that my header is exactly the same in both functions.
I am using requests module to call the endpoints.  I have a feeling this is related to how Flask dispatches requests and manages session or contexts, but I can't figure out why!

Any hints/tips?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys!  It was an error on my part due to copy/paste, where I was still including auth on the request:

resp = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password), headers=headers)

Removing the auth parameter fixed my issue.

Note: In Jupyter notebook or command-line, the above still works, which is why took a while to figure it out :-<